# Symfony2 console HelperSet

Tags: php, symfony, console, doctrine-orm

i'm making application using Symfony2 components, and i got stuck with symfony console. The problem is that i initialize console

```
$objectRepository = ObjectRepository::getInstance();

$console = $objectRepository->get('console');
if ( ! $console instanceof \Symfony\Component\Console\Application) {
    echo 'Failed to initialize console.' . PHP_EOL;
}

$helperSet = $console->getHelperSet();
$helperSet->set(new EntityManagerHelper($objectRepository->get('entity_manager')), 'em');

$console->run();
```

And i have doctrine create command alias which is

```
namespace My\Console\Command;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand as BaseCommand;

class CreateCommand extends BaseCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->setName('doctrine:schema:update');
    }

}
```

Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand is using em helper, and the problem is in [Symfony\Component\Console\Application doRun() method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L192)

```
$command = $this->find($name);
$this->runningCommand = $command;
$statusCode = $command->run($input, $output);
```

Application keeps 3 helpers in HelperSet which are (dialog, format, entityManager and em (em is an alias for entityManager)). After command is found, command does not inherit Application helper set and has only default dialog and format helpers.

I have solution to extend symfony default Application class and rewrite doRun() method, but that's not the best way.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish by extending the schema create command from doctrine? you shouldn't be doing that unless you're doing something quite weird... and why are you manually instantiating the console? where in your code are you doing this?

Comment: @fd8s0 I want it to be called as doctrine:schema:create and not to be an alias. How should i instantiating console? I have configuration which configures console without helperset, then i store it into ObjectRepository. in console file i call object repo to fetch console application and then i set helpers.

Comment: you shouldn't have to modify this command at all, and I don't know why do you want to instantiate the console... I think you just skipped some important part of the documentation or somewhere at the beginning of your thinking process you forked out of the right way... schema update is a command written inside doctrine, you make it work in your application with configuration, not by changing the command... unless as I said, you're planning on changing doctrine's functionality, which is not something people do very often

Comment: @fd8s0 What should i do if i want to rename command?

Comment: why do you want to rename the command?

Comment: @fd8s0 to organize commands in my way. Keep in mind that i'm not using Symfony2 framework, i use only Symfony components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like application and command can have different helper sets, so i solved problem with

```
namespace My\Console\Command;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand as BaseCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CreateCommand extends BaseCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        parent::configure();

        $this->setName('doctrine:schema:create');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->setHelperSet($this->getApplication()->getHelperSet());

        parent::execute($input, $output);
    }

}
```